# use the speak sound of google translator in android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

i am trying to make an android app and i need to use google translator app to copy text from my android application to *Clip board*  then past it in google translator application at last i want to play the sound of listening the translation from english to arabic language. 
this is my simple code :

```
ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
    ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", "Text to copy HI ");
    clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
    Intent LaunchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.apps.translate");
    startActivity(LaunchIntent);
    String textToPaste = null;
    textToPaste = clip.getItemAt(0).getText().toString();
```

can here any one help me ? 
thank you

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: i want the text of the ClipboardManager paste in google translator app i cant do that @AshishAhuja